# Iterating through a variable's characters in pug to style them

Tags: pug, email-templates

I am using email-templates and pug to send some mails.
I have a verification code I would like to send out nicely framed, with each character in a box, for instance to do something of this kind:

```
table(style='border-spacing: 6px')
  tr
    th(style='padding: 4px; border: 0.1em solid #CCC; border-radius: 5px;') A
    th(style='padding: 4px; border: 0.1em solid #CCC; border-radius: 5px;') B
    th(style='padding: 4px; border: 0.1em solid #CCC; border-radius: 5px;') C
```

I'd like to do this using a loop if possible, knowing that the code to display is passed as `{locals: {code: 'ABC'}}` to email-templates (and that it has more characters).

Is this possible? The resulting html should be quite simple, to display nicely in all mail clients.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`each` loop](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#each) to iterate through each character in the string, since strings are arrays:

```
table(style='border-spacing: 6px')
  tr
    each character in code
      th(style='...') #{character}
```

However, it should be noted that this isn't semantic HTML and will be confusing for people using assistive technology. Each character in the code isn't a table column heading, and shouldn't be marked up as such.

Instead, consider using semantic elements and then styling those to look the way you want. A more semantic way to mark this up would be to put the code in a paragraph, with each character in a span. Spans allow you to style each character, but they don't impart any semantic meaning, so it will be interpreted as just a paragraph, which is good.

```
section
  h2 Verification Code
  p
    each character in code
      span #{character}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!! And thanks for the comment on accessibility, I will use span's instead. As a side note, should the paragraph wrapping that code's characters be identified in any way, to make it clear to assistive software that it's all part of one code (give it a name, an id, other?). In any case, thanks again.

Comment: The section and heading should be a sufficient label for assistive tech.